# separate students according to their academic performance(s), singular or plural?

Tags: word-usage, singular-vs-plural

> "Separate students according to their academic performance(s)."

(For example, their test results.) Should I use singular or plural in this phrase?

I did some research, but the example [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165661/performance-plural-vs-singular) is quite different than mine.

Comment: Either is acceptable, but you can easily avoid the problem in several ways. The simplest is to omit the possessive pronoun: _Separate students according to academic performance._  Or consider: _Separate students by academic performance._ (Thank you for your question, @EmmaXL :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance should be used in your original sentence.  Performances would be for things such as performing in a play or something like that.

Performance, in this case, is a group noun like "clothing". It would apply to the whole of their academic performance.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the singular "performance" could be used

> Separate students according to their academic performance *(into different groups)*.
>   *according to each student's individual academic performance*

which would result in

> The academic performance**s** of the students in a given group will be similar.

Comment: sorry, I didn't quite understand. Would they mean different things? Why can I use singular? Each student has their own performance and everyone's performance is different.

Comment: Using the singular would mean that each student has a single "performance" measure which is an aggregate of their accomplishment, and this measure is then used to group various students together. Don't confuse  a student's "performance" (collective measure) with an actor's "performances" (to perform *something*).  If you turned the sentence around "We used academic performance to separate the students into groups." or "We used the academic performances of the students to separate into groups."